# steps to Make ubuntu system as shared GIT repository

Tags: git, ubuntu-12.04

steps to Make my **ubuntu system as shared GIT repository**. I'm using ubuntu12.04. i have installed git. how to change as remote repository

Comment: I found this useful -> https://www.kennwilson.com/notes/2013/08/self-hosted-remote-git-repositories/

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "shared git repository"? Do you want to access it from other hosts? Do you need some kind of access control for different users?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a repository in your home directory with `git init --bare repo.git`.

After this you could clone this repository (from another host) using `git clone user@host:repo`. (This only requires ssh access to your host.)

Comment: Thank you i have created remote repository successfully